# Group results in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I have the following query:

```
query Results {
  dirs {
    nodes {
        id
        name
        description
    }
  }
  files {
    nodes {
      id
      dirId
      name
      description
    }
  }
}
```

which result is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "dirs": {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "dir_1",
                    "description": "desc_1",
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "dir_2",
                    "description": "desc_2",
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "dir_3",
                    "description": "desc_3",
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "dir_4",
                    "description": "desc_4",
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "dir_5",
                    "description": "desc_5",
                },
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "dir_6",
                    "description": "desc_6",
                },
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "name": "dir_7",
                    "description": "desc_7",
                },
            ]
        },
        "files": {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "dirId": 1,
                    "name": "file_1",
                    "description": "desc_1",
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "dirId": 2,
                    "name": "file_2",
                    "description": "desc_2",
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "dirId": 2,
                    "name": "file_3",
                    "description": "desc_3",
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "dirId": 3,
                    "name": "file_4",
                    "description": "desc_4",
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "dirId": 4,
                    "name": "file_5",
                    "description": "desc_5",
                },
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "dirId": 6,
                    "name": "file_6",
                    "description": "desc_6",
                },
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "dirId": 6,
                    "name": "file_7",
                    "description": "desc_7",
                },
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "dirId": 7,
                    "name": "file_8",
                    "description": "desc_8",
                },
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "dirId": 7,
                    "name": "file_9",
                    "description": "desc_9",
                },
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "dirId": 7,
                    "name": "file_10",
                    "description": "desc_10",
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have access to server graphql part and I don't know how to define query to get this result:

```
{
    data: {
        dirs: {
            nodes: [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "dir_1",
                    "description": "desc_1",
                    files: {
                        nodes: [
                            {
                                "id": 1,
                                "dirId": 1,
                                "name": "file_1",
                                "description": "desc_1",
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "dir_2",
                    "description": "desc_2",
                    files: {
                        nodes: [
                            {
                                "id": 2,
                                "dirId": 2,
                                "name": "file_2",
                                "description": "desc_2",
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 3,
                                "dirId": 2,
                                "name": "file_3",
                                "description": "desc_3",
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "dir_3",
                    "description": "desc_3",
                    files: {
                        nodes: [
                            {
                                "id": 4,
                                "dirId": 3,
                                "name": "file_4",
                                "description": "desc_4",
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "dir_4",
                    "description": "desc_4",
                    files: {
                        nodes: [
                            {
                                "id": 5,
                                "dirId": 4,
                                "name": "file_5",
                                "description": "desc_5",
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "dir_5",
                    "description": "desc_5",
                    files: {
                        nodes: [
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "dir_6",
                    "description": "desc_6",
                    files: {
                        nodes: [
                            {
                                "id": 6,
                                "dirId": 6,
                                "name": "file_6",
                                "description": "desc_6",
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 7,
                                "dirId": 6,
                                "name": "file_7",
                                "description": "desc_7",
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "name": "dir_7",
                    "description": "desc_7",
                    files: {
                        nodes: [
                            {
                                "id": 8,
                                "dirId": 7,
                                "name": "file_8",
                                "description": "desc_8",
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 9,
                                "dirId": 7,
                                "name": "file_9",
                                "description": "desc_9",
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 10,
                                "dirId": 7,
                                "name": "file_10",
                                "description": "desc_10",
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible, because nodes don't have files property. You must fetch separate then map to another array.

Comment: @NijatAliyev can you provide a pseudocode how to achieve that please?

Comment: Similar to what Nijat stated, the server should be able to supply `files` field in a `node` object. You may test the server response by moving `files` section in `nodes`. If fails with an error indicating invalid field, you may consider grouping the result on the client side (and it would be a different question depending on the language you use, your graphql library etc.)

Comment: I think I tried to move files section into nodes and it didn't work, but when I tried it now, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to move files section into nodes and it worked:

```
query Results {
  dirs {
    nodes {
        id
        name
        description
files {
    nodes {
      id
      dirId
      name
      description
    }
  }
    }
  }
}
```